# Resque Workers from other hosts registered and active on my system

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, resque

The Rails application I'm currently working on is hosted at Amazon EC2 servers. It's using Resque for running background jobs, and there are 2 such instances (would-be production and a stage). Also I've mounted Resque monitoring web app to the /resque route (on stage only).

Here is my question:
Why there are workers from multiple hosts registered within my stage system and how can I avoid this?

Some additional details: 
I see workers from apparently 3 different machines, but only 2 of them I managed to identify -  the stage(obviously) and the production. The third has another address format(starts with domU) and haven't any clue what it could be.

[image: foreign resque workers]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're sharing a single Redis server across multiple resque server environments.

The best way to do this safely is to use separate Redis servers or separate Redis databases or namespaces. The Redis-namespace gem can be used with Resque to isolate each environments Resque queues and worker data.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really help you with what the unknown one is, but I had something similar happen when moving hosts and having dns names change. The only way I found to clear out the old ones was to stop all workers on the machine, fire up IRB, `require 'resque'` and look at `Resque.workers`. This will list all the workers resque knows about, which in your case will include about 20 bogus ones. You can then do:

```
Resque.workers.each do {|worker| worker.unregister_worker}
```

This should prune all the not-really-there workers and get you back to a proper display of the real workers.